# List of all Abelian groups of order $1188$?

Tags: group-theory

I am working on a question that asks me to list all abelian groups of order $1188$.

I have a list that I will put below that I obtained using the classification of finite abelian groups.

My question is could someone verify whether my answer is correct and is in fact a list of all such groups.

Is there some kind of way to check answers like this online or do you have to manually compute them to verify?

Anyway here is the list:

> $$C_{1188}$$
>
> $$C_{3} \times C_{396}$$
>
> $$C_{2} \times C_{594}$$
>
> $$C_{6} \times C_{198}$$
>
> $$C_{3} \times C_{3} \times C_{132}$$
>
> $$C_{3} \times C_{6} \times C_{66}$$

Much obliged!

Comment: $1188=11*2^2*3^3$.  It therefore suffices to find all abelian groups of orders $11$ (there is 1), $2^2$ (there are 2), and $3^3$ (there are 3), and then take all the corresponding products.  This gives a slightly different list of the same length as your list, and without checking, it seems likely that the groups in each list are isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

For any prime factorisation $p_1^{a_1}...p_n^{a_n}$ , the number of abelian groups of this order are $\pi(a1)*...*\pi (a_n)$ where pi denotes partitions...apply it here to be absolutely sure.1*2*3=6 so you can do this in general for any order